# How can I hide file directory

Tags: python, windows, file, directory, hide

How to hide this text after I do some functions. I mean i see every time ***"PS C:\Users\marec\Desktop\Python>"*** in terminal/console

*Here I have e screenshot:* [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nOPM8.png)

Comment: cd to there and use `echo off`

Comment: im seriously new and i don't know where to paste this

Comment: in cmd use `cd` or if You are already there (in the directory with Your script) type `echo off` and press enter. then it will hide it all and You can simply type `py script_name.py`

Comment: can you send me photo or something... :/

Answer (score 0):

go to Your directory where You have You file and then

[image]

and then press enter and continue with running Your script

```
py your_script.py
```